# Bootstrap carousel width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to do a bootstrap carousel with full width for the images (width: 100%) and a fixed height but if I set the width to 100% the height automacally is taking the 100% too

I don't sure if the problem is in my files

```
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="active item">
    <%= image_tag "slider/slide-bg-1.jpg", class: "tales" %>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <%= image_tag "slider/slide-bg-2.jpg", class: "tales" %>
  </div>
  <div class="item"> 
    <%= image_tag "slider/slide-bg-3.jpg", class: "tales" %>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Carousel nav -->
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
```

and my css file

```
.tales {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Are you trying to make it responsive? If you are then I would just recommend the following:

```
.tales {
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner{
  width:100%;
  max-height: 200px !important;
}
```

However, the best way to handle this responsively would be thru the use of media queries like such:

```
/* Smaller than standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {}

/* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {}

/* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}

/* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {}

/* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {}
```

Comment: @Eduro thanks for the answer.I was facing with below issue where captions are missing for the slides.using 1920 x 1080  size images and full images are not visible.

Answer (score 14):

If you use **bootstrap 4** Alpha and you have an error with the height of the images in chrome, I have a solution:
The documentation of bootstrap 4 says this:

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution:**

The solution is to put "div" around the image, with the class ".container", like this:

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="images/proyecto_0.png" alt="First slide" class="d-block img-fluid">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

I recommend the following for Bootstrap 3

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  min-height: 500px;    /* Set slide height here */

}
```

Comment: That stretches the image... :-/

Comment: Zeth it works if all your images have the same size and you use that exact size.

Comment: use `max-height` instead of `min-height`

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an older post but Bootstrap is still alive and kicking!

Slightly different to @Eduardo's post, I had to modify:

```
#myCarousel.carousel.slide {
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 400px; !important
}
```

When I only modified `.carousel-inner {}`, the actual image was fixed size but the left/right controls were displaying incorrectly off to the side of the `div`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

My height changed to its original height while my slide was animating to the left, ( in a responsive website )

so I fixed it with CSS only :

```
.carousel .item.left img{
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just put height="400px" into image attribute like

```
<img class="d-block w-100" src="../assets/img/natural-backdrop.jpg" height="400px" alt="First slide">
```

Comment: You don't need to place units inside `height` or `width` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you just want to change the height of the element the image takes up, this will be the code that will help.

```css
.carousel-item {
    height: 600px !important;
}
```

However, this won't make the size of the image dynamic, it will simply crop the image to its size.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a responsive sample that works well for me and I find it to be quite simple have a look at my carousel-fill:

```
.carousel-fill {
    height: -o-calc(100vh - 165px) !important;
    height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 165px) !important;
    height: -moz-calc(100vh - 165px) !important;
    height: calc(100vh - 165px) !important;
    width: auto !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel-item {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

my navigation height+footer are a hair less then 165px so that value works for me. take off a value that fits for you, I overrdide the .carousel-item from bootstrap so make sure by videos are centered.

my carousel looks like this, note the "carousel-fill" on the video tag.

```
<div>
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade text-center" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <video autoplay muted class="carousel-fill">
                        <source src="~/Video/CATSTrade.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h2>CATS IV Trade engine</h2>
                        <p>Automated trading for high ROI</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <video muted loop class="carousel-fill">
                        <source src="~/Video/itrs.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h2>Machine learning</h2>
                        <p>Machine learning specialist</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <video muted loop class="carousel-fill">
                        <source src="~/Video/frequency.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Low latency development</h3>
                        <p>Create ultra fast systems with our consultants</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="~/Images/data pipeline faded.png" class="carousel-fill" />

                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Big Data</h3>
                        <p>Maintain, generate, and host big data</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

in case some one needs to control the videos like i do, I start and stop the videos like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.carousel').carousel({ interval: 8000 })
            $('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (args) {
                var videoList = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
                switch (args.from) {
                    case 0:
                        videoList[0].pause();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        videoList[1].pause();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        videoList[2].pause();
                        break;
                }
                switch (args.to) {
                    case 0:
                        videoList[0].play();

                        break;
                    case 1:
                        videoList[1].play();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        videoList[2].play();
                        break;
                }
            })

        });
</script>
```