# bootstrap carousel image dimensions

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have probs in the dimensions of the image to be placed inside carousel. Any image I load (with different dimensions px) I get an image elongated all over the carouse width and not proportional to the original..
How should I fix the CSS ? Can I place the image at the center of the carousel without having it prolonged to the left/right borders? Here is my CSS:

```
.carousel {
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 100;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 10;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: I use a carrousel in my page and in the 'item' part i use: 

`<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style='height:450px;'>         
     <div class="item col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 active" style="height:440px;">...</div>
 <div class="item col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" style="height:440px;">...</div>`

for positioning the item div in the center and control the width and all works fine.

Comment: This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481334/bootstrap-carousel-width-and-height

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put that css code into your  css file

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```